# Sending Post request with curl using nested objects

Tags: node.js, curl, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema in which i have to do a POST PUT DELETE request on. However when i send the curl command the server outputs the following

```
{ ValidationError: data validation failed: categories.url_name: Path `categories.url_name` is required., categories.name: Path `categories.name` is required.
```

It tells me the data wasnt sent through the curl command correctly. So i would like to know how to properly write a curl post with nested json objects

My mongoose schema is the following :

```
var DataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
categories: {
    name :  {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    url_name : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    }
  }

})
```

And my curl command  is this one

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{“categories”:” { name :1, url_name :example }” ' http://localhost:4200/add
```

Is there something wrong with the json or is it the schema i´ve created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your curl request is not formatted correctly. Try:

```
curl \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -X POST \
  -d '{"categories": { "name" :1, "url_name": "example" }}' \
  http://localhost:4200/add
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `curl` command had extra double quotes.  Please try:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"categories": { "name" :1, "url_name" : "example" }}' http://localhost:4200/add
```

Comment: it returns unexpected token e in json at position 40

Comment: I added quotes around "example"